# Including probability density of poly-disperse ensembles in a fitting of a Langevin-Derivative function

Tags: python, model, curve-fitting, model-fitting

I am aware that following will require patience and I do appreciate the effort you will be giving.

I have a measured data, which represent the derivative of the magnetic moment : dM/dH. A good mathematical model of M(H) curve is the langevin function : where:

> M(H) = 1/coth(xi) - 1/xi , xi = cte*Vi³

so the derivative of the magnetic moment can be obtained from the derivative of the derivative of the langevin function :

> dM/dH = 1/xi² - 1/(sinh²(xi))

For the fitting I used this function as a fitting function :

```
    def langevinDeriv(xx):
        if not hasattr(xx, '__iter__'):
            xx = [ xx ]
        res = np.zeros(len(xx))
        eps = 1e-1
        for i in range(len(xx)):
            x = xx[i]
            if np.fabs(x) < eps:
                res[i] =  1./3. - x**2/15. + 2.* x**4 / 189. - x**6/675. + 2.* x**8 / 10395. - 1382. * x**10 / 58046625. + 4. * x**12 / 1403325.
            else:
                res[i] = (1./x**2 - 1./np.sinh(x)**2)
        return res
```

and minimized the error with a simple Least square function.

Here is what I got : [comparaison : fit and data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBaPH.png)

I would say, that the fit is not good, because actually I don't have one diameter of particles but polydisperse ensembles with different diameters and so with different Langevin_derivative functions.

My question is, how can I integrate this probability density for the diameter to my fitting function, so that the program would fit to a probability distribution and not a single Diameter Vi. The function of the probability density is given here: 
http://www.originlab.de/doc/LabTalk/ref/Lognpdf-func

Comment: Obviously there is some convolution, but a bigger problem seems to be the abrupt drop at the end that is not at all captured by the model at hand. Any idea what s happening there?

Comment: I have a really bad SNR there. So I might just ignore the drop. Any idea how I can define the convolution kernel please ?

Comment: I'll try to think about it. For now, another question. To me it looks like there are 4 obvious drops, from which I tend to conclude that there are 4 main sizes. Do you have a size distribution of poly-disperse system? Otherwise I's go for summing up 4.

Comment: Thank you very much !!!! I would say that it is a log-normal distribution

Comment: Salut Tassou, can you post the data? Btw, the drop at the edges will always mess up your fit, one needs to take care of this. Is it a correlation effect in your particles that the single particle model does not account for?

Comment: Is it the diameter or the volume that is log-normal? I guess it is the diameter?

Answer (score 0):

So I fiddled around bit. As mentioned in the comments, fit will never give super results as the model does not capture the drop in signal at the ends (as well as the step-like behaviour on the graph). The results, however looks much better than a simple Langevin derivative. I basically sum up functions with different particle volume  providing a max diameter. You can control the max diameter and the number of diameters used in the range of 0 to max diameter. The only two fit parameters are the standard deviation and the overall amplitude. In detail you have to be careful with the scaling to get physically meaningful results. I played already a little with `n` and `d_max` finding that in my scaling `15,3` is OK. I guess `d_max` should be sufficiently larger than `s` and `n` reasonably large to have several values near the max of the log-normal distribution.

[image]

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit ,leastsq


def log_gauss(x,s):
    if x==0 or s==0:
        out=0
    else:
        exponent=-np.log(x)**2/(2*s**2)
        if abs(exponent)>100:
            out=0
        else:
        out=np.exp(exponent)/np.sqrt(2 * np.pi * x**2 * s**2)
return out

def langevin(x,epsilon=1e-4):
    if abs(x)<epsilon:
        out=x/3.-x**3/45.+2*x**5/945.
    else:
        out=1./np.tanh(x)-1./x
    return out

def langevin_d(x,epsilon=1e-4):
    if abs(x)<epsilon:
        out=1/3.-x**2/15.+2*x**4/189.
    elif abs(x)>100.:
        out= 1./x**2
    else:
        out=-1./np.sinh(x)**2+1./x**2
    return out

def langevin_d_distributed(h,s,n=25,dMax=10):
    diaList=np.linspace(.01,dMax,n)
    pdiaList=[log_gauss(d,s) for d in diaList]
    volList=[d**3 for d in diaList]
    dm=0
    for v,p in zip(volList,pdiaList):
        dm+=p*langevin_d(h*v)
    return dm

def residuals(parameters,dataPoint,n=25,dMax=10):
    a,s = abs(parameters)
    dist = [y -a*langevin_d_distributed(x,s,n=n,dMax=dMax) for x,y in dataPoint] 
    return dist

meas_x,meas_y=np.loadtxt('OBaPH.txt', delimiter=',',unpack=True)
meas_x=meas_x*300
meas_y=meas_y-min(meas_y)
hList=np.linspace(0,8,155)

langevinDList=[langevin_d(h) for h in hList]
langevinDList=np.array(langevinDList)/langevinDList[0]

distList_01=[langevin_d_distributed(h,.29) for h in hList]
distList_01=np.array(distList_01)/distList_01[0]

dataTupel=zip(meas_x,meas_y)
estimate = [1,0.29]
bestFitValues=dict()
myFit=dict()
for nnn,ddd in [(15,3),(15,1.5),(15,10),(5,3),(25,3)]:
    bestFitValues[(nnn,ddd)], ier = leastsq(residuals, estimate,args=(dataTupel,nnn,ddd))
    print bestFitValues[(nnn,ddd)]
    myFit[(nnn,ddd)]= [bestFitValues[(nnn,ddd)][0]*langevin_d_distributed(h,bestFitValues[(nnn,ddd)][1],n=nnn,dMax=ddd) for h in hList]

fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

ax.plot(meas_x,meas_y,linestyle='',marker='o',label='rescaled data')
ax.plot(hList,langevinDList,label='Langevin')
ax.plot(hList,distList_01,label='log_norm test')
for key,val in myFit.iteritems():    
    ax.plot(hList,val,label=key)
ax.legend(loc=0)

plt.show()
```